# My RecyclerView doesnt show up and I get this error : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

okay so i'm trying to get information about an item from the solditem class
then i want to show it in a recycler view in another class (i implemented parcelable) but here is the problem
it doesnt show anything and it throws this message :
" E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout "
i made sure the arraylist is passed correctly but even tho , it doesnt work;
here is the files concerned :

1- solditem.java :

```
package com.example.stock;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SoldItem implements Parcelable {
   public String dateVente;
   public String nomClient;
   public String nomProduit;
   public float prixProduitUnitaire;
   public float prixProduitTotal;
   public int quantiteProduit;


   public SoldItem() {
   }

   public SoldItem(String nomClient, String nomProduit, float prixProduitUnitaire,
                   int quantiteProduit)
   {
       this.dateVente=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());;
       this.nomClient=nomClient;
       this.nomProduit=nomProduit;
       this.prixProduitUnitaire=prixProduitUnitaire;
       this.quantiteProduit=quantiteProduit;
       this.prixProduitTotal = (quantiteProduit * prixProduitUnitaire);


   }
   public SoldItem(String nomProduit, float prixProduitUnitaire,
                   int quantiteProduit)
   {

       this.nomProduit=nomProduit;
       this.prixProduitUnitaire=prixProduitUnitaire;
       this.quantiteProduit=quantiteProduit;



   }


   protected SoldItem(Parcel in) {
       dateVente = in.readString();
       nomClient = in.readString();
       nomProduit = in.readString();
       prixProduitUnitaire = in.readFloat();
       prixProduitTotal = in.readFloat();
       quantiteProduit = in.readInt();
   }

   public static final Creator<SoldItem> CREATOR = new Creator<SoldItem>() {
       @Override
       public SoldItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new SoldItem(in);
       }

       @Override
       public SoldItem[] newArray(int size) {
           return new SoldItem[size];
       }
   };

   public String getDateVente() {
       return dateVente;
   }

   public String getNomClient() {
       return nomClient;
   }

   public String getNomProduit() {
       return nomProduit;
   }

   public float getPrixProduitUnitaire() {
       return prixProduitUnitaire;
   }

   public float getPrixProduitTotal() {
       return getPrixProduitUnitaire()*getQuantiteProduit();
   }

   public int getQuantiteProduit() {
       return quantiteProduit;
   }


   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "SoldItem{" +
               "dateVente='" + dateVente + '\'' +
               ", nomClient='" + nomClient + '\'' +
               ", nomProduit='" + nomProduit + '\'' +
               ", prixProduitUnitaire=" + prixProduitUnitaire +
               ", prixProduitTotal=" + prixProduitTotal +
               ", quantiteProduit=" + quantiteProduit +
               '}';
   }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
       parcel.writeString(dateVente);
       parcel.writeString(nomClient);
       parcel.writeString(nomProduit);
       parcel.writeFloat(prixProduitUnitaire);
       parcel.writeFloat(prixProduitTotal);
       parcel.writeInt(quantiteProduit);
   }
}
```

2- sellproduct.java

```
 package com.example.stock;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SellProduct extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
   public RecyclerView recyclerview;
    public FloatingActionButton additem;
    public ItemAdapter myadapter = new ItemAdapter();
    public ArrayList<SoldItem> filelist ;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sale);
        additem = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

        recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2item);
        filelist = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("filelist");
        additem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(SellProduct.this, "update réussi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent b = new Intent(SellProduct.this, ItemToSell.class);
                startActivity(b);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (filelist != null) {
            Toast.makeText(SellProduct.this,  "uiiiii" + filelist.get(0).toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             BuildRecycleView();


        }
    }

    private void setRecycleViewButtons() {

        myadapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                //rien
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
                removeItem2(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onModifyClick(int position) {
                UpdateItemClient(position);

            }


        });
    }

    private void BuildRecycleView() {

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        myadapter = new ItemAdapter(filelist);
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(myadapter);
        setRecycleViewButtons();

    }

    public void removeItem2(int position) {
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("are you sure you want to remove this item information?")
                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SoldItem item = new SoldItem();
                        item = filelist.get(position);
                        filelist.remove(position);
                        myadapter.setListeClientsComplete(filelist);
                        myadapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();

    }

    public void UpdateItemClient(int position) {

        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("confirmation")
                .setMessage("are you sure you want to modify this item information?")
                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SoldItem item = filelist.get(position);
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateItem.class);
                        i.putExtra("item", item);
                        i.putExtra("position", position);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();

    }





}
```

and the adapter class 3-itemadapter.java

```
package com.example.stock;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>  {
    private ArrayList<SoldItem> listeItem;
    private ArrayList<SoldItem> listeItemComplete;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public ItemAdapter() {

    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
        void onDeleteClick(int position);
        void onModifyClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;
        public TextView mTextView3;
        public TextView mTextView4;
        public ImageView mDeleteImage;
        public ImageView mModifyImage;


        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);


            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomp);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qte);
            mTextView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uni_pricee);
            mTextView4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.total_pricee);
            mDeleteImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn2);
            mModifyImage= itemView.findViewById(R.id.modify_btn2);

            // si je clique sur un item de recycle view, je declance la mathode onClick, qui appel la fonction onItemClick qui est implementé dans AfficherClientsActivity
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // si je clique sur le button Delete d'un item de recycleview
            mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onDeleteClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mModifyImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onModifyClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });



        }

    }

    public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<SoldItem> Liste) {
        this.listeItem = Liste;
        listeItemComplete = new ArrayList<SoldItem>(listeItem);
    }

    public void setListeClientsComplete(ArrayList<SoldItem> listeClientsComplete) {
        this.listeItemComplete = listeClientsComplete;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one_card_item, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder evh = new ItemViewHolder(v,mListener);
        return evh;
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SoldItem currentItem = listeItem.get(position);

        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getNomProduit());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getQuantiteProduit());
        holder.mTextView3.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getPrixProduitUnitaire()));
        holder.mTextView4.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getPrixProduitTotal()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listeItem.size();
    }




}
```

and here are the xml files :
sellproduct.xml (where i want to display the recyclerview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/celeste">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="336dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:hint="Customer Name"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_client"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textColor="#546E7A"
            tools:text=" " />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/cg_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.842"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/cg_blue"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.562"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.197" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview2item"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="262dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

thank you in advance : )

Comment: Initialise your layout manager like 'LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)'

Comment: @TusharLathiya i just tried it and unfortunately i still have the same problem

Comment: call myadapter.notifyDataStateChanged(); when you get the data. you just call below recyclerview.setAdapter(myadapter);

Comment: Is `filelist` null in `onResume`? The error suggests you never attach an adapter, which would happen if that is null. (Do you see the "uiiiii" toast?). Also, it's usually best to do adapter creation and attachment in `onCreate` rather than `onResume`

Comment: @TylerV Yes , I do see the "uiii" toast which is why it's weird because that means that the item is correctly added to the the arraylist (filelist) and thus it isn't null also about the adapter creation thank you for the advice ! i'm going to correct that

Comment: @TusharLathiya okay i'm gonna try this , thank you !!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well if none of the suggestions fixes it you'll need to make a MCVE (like the bot said) so someone else could run it too, otherwise we just have to guess. I don't see anything obviously wrong.